# echarts (line chart) how to connect when no data

Tags: javascript, echarts

img1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EbSU.png

img2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeB0p.png

echarts (line chart) how to connect when no data,I want to img2

demo link:
http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/line1.html

Answer (score 5):

Using echarts v4.2.1

Here is the documentation: 
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.connectNulls

Take a notice that it's for series of `type: 'line'`

```
connectNulls: true
```

> Whether to connect the line across null points.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use echarts v3

```
connectNulls: true
```